# Blazor server-side deployment problems (.net 6)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I recently added a few new pages to a functioning Blazor server site.  After publishing the newly-updated files, things aren't working properly.  The foyer isolated .css isn't working, and after logging in, no content on the main page is displaying (it's not there at all when inspecting the page in Chrome, so I suspect Authorization is failing somehow).

The app runs in debug mode on my dev machine, but does not function correctly in release mode.

Neither version works properly when uploaded to the server.  **I tried the "self-contained" publish mode, which I expect to work 100% of the time since it (supposedly) links all required assemblies.**  But it works (i.e. doesn't work) in the same way that the Frame-dependent version did.

Can someone tell me how to identify the issue, or has anyone had a similar problem before?

Comment: Did you upgrade .NET or packages to new version? and did you upgrade the server .NET?